# TSQL Conditional IS NULL and = Operator

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to write this in one statement, how to do this?

```
-- Is there a block for this user?
SELECT @BlockID = BlockID FROM [Blocks]  
WHERE UserID = @UserID

-- If not exists, get the default one
IF @BlockID IS NULL  
SELECT @BlockID = BlockID FROM [Blocks]  
WHERE UserID IS NULL
```

Comment: This is just an example with two cases, I have more cases 1) Get User specific Block 2) If not exists, Get Group's default block 2) If not exists, Get Program's default block 3) Finally nothing exists, get default block. Above I made it short with two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coalesce`.  It also expands to more than two cases easily.

```
select
  @BlockID = coalesce(u.BlockID, d.BlockID)
from
  Blocks d
  left join Blocks u on u.UserID = @UserID
where
  d.UserID is null
```

Comment: +1: The OP didn't mention the additional cases initially, but your answer will work well for a generalized solution.  Nice!

Comment: Easy to read and follow, how about performance? Is this better or worser than in my example?

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @BlockID = (SELECT TOP 1 BlockID
                FROM [Blocks]
                WHERE UserID IS NULL OR UserID = @UserID
                ORDER BY CASE WHEN UserID IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET @BlockID = (SELECT BlockID FROM [Blocks] WHERE UserID IS NULL)
```

Comment: That only gets the default blockid value - it will never get the one associated with @Userid if it exists.

Comment: @Lukasz: This would return always the default Block right? Whatif, there is User specific block exists?